# Revmob worked and now that it is in the app store, it doesnt work

Tags: ios, iphone, revmob, revmobads

So basically Revmob worked in my app, tested it on ios7/ios6, everything was fine so I submitted it to the app store and now that it is in the app store, it stopped working.  I tested it in xcode and got this message in Xcode:

[RevMob] Testing mode off
2014-02-25 19:35:54.659 [32098:a0b] [RevMob] Initializing Fullscreen.
2014-02-25 19:35:55.249 [32098:a0b] [RevMob] Invalid App Id or Placement Id (404).
2014-02-25 19:35:55.249 [32098:a0b] [RevMob] Failed with errro: {
}

I dont understand how it worked before and now it doesnt even work in the simulator. Any help with this would be ever so greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Also has the same problem

Comment: is your app rejected first time?

Answer (score 0):

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"ID"];
[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
```

Comment: I have: [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"ID"];
[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];

Comment: i dont have testing mode on.